# Find the maximum entries using xslt

Tags: xslt, max

I have a table and I want to find the maximum entries from `tbody and thead`. I have mentioned the table code below.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <row>
        <entry>
            <p>aaa</p>
            <p>aaa</p>
        </entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry>
            <p>bbb</p>
            <p>bbb</p>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <p>ccc</p>
            <p>ccc</p>
        </entry>
    </row>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <row>
        <entry>
            <p>ddd</p>
            <p>ddd</p>
        </entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry>
            <p>eee</p>
            <p>eee</p>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <p>fff</p>
            <p>fff</p>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <p>ggg</p>
            <p>ggg</p>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <p>hhh</p>
            <p>hhh</p>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <p>iii</p>
            <p>iii</p>
        </entry>
    </row>
    <row>
        <entry>
            <p>jjj</p>
            <p>jjj</p>
        </entry>
        <entry>
            <p>kkk</p>
            <p>kkk</p>
        </entry>
    </row>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

It means here maximum entry count is `5` and it is xpath is `table/tbody/row[2]/entry`. I want to find the maxmium entry value between  `thead` and `tbody`.

I have used xslt code for this. But it is not work properly. It always returns me `0` as the answer.

```
<xsl:template match="table">
   <xsl:variable name="is-notempty-table" select="max(count(thead/row/entry))" />
   <xsl:value-of select="$is-notempty-table" />
</xsl:template>
```

Help me to solve this.

Comment: Your template matches `tgroup` but there is no such element in your XML....

Comment: @TimC I am sorry..It was a mistake...Now i corrected it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with doing this...

```
<xsl:variable name="is-notempty-table" select="max(count(thead/row/entry))" />
```

Is that `count(thead/row/entry)` is only going to return a single value; namely the count of all `entry` nodes in the `thead`. (And it will return 3, not 0). If you want to find the maximum count of `entry` nodes for the rows within `thead`, the expression you want is this

```
<xsl:variable name="is-notempty-table" select="max(thead/row/count(entry))" />
```

Or, for `tbody`

```
<xsl:variable name="is-notempty-table" select="max(tbody/row/count(entry))" />
```

Or, to check the entire table...

```
<xsl:variable name="is-notempty-table" select="max(*/row/count(entry))" />
```

As an aside, the use of the variable name `is-notempty-table` suggests you are just wanting to check if the table has `entry` nodes in? If so, you can just do this...

```
<xsl:variable name="is-notempty-table" select="*/row/entry" />
<xsl:if test="$is-notempty-table">Table is not empty</xsl:if>
```

Comment: If i want to use for-each for iterate this max number times how can i use the variable. `<xsl:for-each select="$is-notempty-table"> <colname posi="{position()}"/> </xsl:for-each>` when I used this way it not works.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `<xsl:template match="table">` it seems you want to compute `max(*/row/count(entry))` (if there are no other children for the table element) or perhaps `max((thead|tbody)/row/count(entry))` if you expect other elements like a tfoot.

Both expressions assume XSLT/XPath 2 or later.

Comment: If i want to use `for-each` for iterate this max number times how can i use the variable.
`<xsl:for-each select="$is-notempty-table">
     <colname posi="{position()}"/>
 </xsl:for-each>`

Comment: The expression computes an integer, if you use it inside a `to` expression e.g. `1 to max((thead|tbody)/row/count(entry))` you get a sequence of integers from 1 to the max value. Not sure how you want to process that further and whether any `for-each` is needed or a good approach, you might want to ask a new question with the necessary details.

Comment: In this answer there is problem. Always return first row entry count.